# Must one give maaser on cash back?

Tags: halacha, money, maaser-tithes

Does one need to give *maaser* on cash back earned, as a percentage of the sum spent, through extensions such as Rakuten or Honey, or via debit/credit card offers?

Is it considered new income, and therefore qualifies for *maaser*, or do we consider it a discount on the original purchase and therefore (as far as I know) not obligated in *maaser*?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33427/759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I allowed to get miles or points for a loan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33427/am-i-allowed-to-get-miles-or-points-for-a-loan)

Comment: @sabbahillel no, I'm not asking a ribbis question, I'm asking a maaser question

Comment: You would only need to return it if you treated the money that you gave him as coming from maaser.

Answer (score 4):

Since the cash back is a proportion of the cash spent, it fits the definition of a rebate (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebate_(marketing)): a form of buying discount [...] paid by way of reduction, return, or refund that is paid retrospectively.) And one does not pay *maaser* on rebates.

Indeed Ask the Rav writes ([here](https://asktherav.com/2835-do-you-need-to-give-maaser-from-credit-card-points-what-if-it-is-given-as-a-credit-statement-or-to-be-used-for-airline-miles/))

> **One need not separate ma’aser from rebates**, even if they are cash back
> rebates.

Similarly, dinonline ([here](https://dinonline.org/2012/03/01/giving-maaser-from-credit-card-points/)) writes

> **For a rebate**, maaser has already been taken from the money, which is
> not considered a new income, and therefore **there is no obligation to
> give maaser again**.

Comment: Would this _din_ apply even though in this case the rebate is coming from a third party (e.g. Rakuten)? Would that not possibly cause it to be considered a new income?

Comment: If you ask for a practical case, then you should as a Rav. But, in my view, since the rebate is function of how much you spend, it is not new income. There is no way to get this "income" unless you spend the money - as such I don't think it as anything else than a discount.